# Upload and Insert File Data in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm creating a file upload system in CodeIgniter, and I have a form that asks for a file name before it uploads to the database. It uses my controller to upload the file to the server. Currently the controller is working, but I need to insert the file name into the table.

**`upload.php`**:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './gfiles/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|psd|pdf|eps|ai|zip|indd|qxt';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = 'TRUE';
    //$config['max_size']   = '100';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload', $error);
    }   
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->db->insert('files', $_POST);

    }
}
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to get the file name into the database properly? The code above also encrypts the filename. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); should contain what you are looking for.

do print_r($data) and you should see the original and encrypted filename.

Comment: Thanks @stef. It is outputting all of the values. There is also an Database Error; A Database Error Occurred, You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Comment: The online manual really is top notch and easy to understand, don't forget to check it every now and then :)

Comment: @doubleplusgood "You must use the "set" method to update an entry stack" for this problem you must set FALSE to database config ‘db_debug’ value to :$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;